# Loading Data from file into tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So i'm making a project organization program in tkinter that has to load previously saved data from a file into a widget in tkinter (Preferably a Label) but I can't figure out how to get only the first line of the file.

I have know idea what to do or where to start

```
from tkinter import *
import time

opened = open("Opened.txt", 'r')
opened = str(opened.read())

root = Tk()

def Tasks():
    global t1, t2, t3, t4, t5


    t1 = Entry(root)
    t1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    t2 = Entry(root)
    t2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    t3 = Entry(root)
    t3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    t4 = Entry(root)
    t4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    t5 = Entry(root)
    t5.grid(row=4, column=1)

    tl1 = Label(root, text="Task 1")
    tl2 = Label(root, text="Task 2")
    tl3 = Label(root, text="Task 3")
    tl4 = Label(root, text="Task 4")
    tl5 = Label(root, text="Task 5")

    tl1.grid(row=0)
    tl2.grid(row=1)
    tl3.grid(row=2)
    tl4.grid(row=3)
    tl5.grid(row=4)

def save():
    task_file = open("Tasks.txt", 'w')

    tlv1 = t1.get()



    tlv2 = t2.get()



    tlv3 = t3.get()



    tlv4 = t4.get()



    tlv5 = t5.get()






    task_file.write("Task 1:" + str(tlv1) + "\n" + "Task 2:" + str(tlv2) 
+ "\n" + "Task 3:" + str(tlv3) + "\n" + "Task 4:" + str(tlv4) + "\n" + 
"Task 5:" + str(tlv5) + "\n")

    if len(t1.get()) == 0 and len(t2.get()) == 0 and len(t3.get()) == 0 and 
len(t4.get()) == 0 and len(t5.get()) == 0:
        nothing = Button(root, text="Nothing to save, click to close", 
command=lambda: nothing.destroy())
        nothing.grid(row=0, column=3)
        task_file.write(" ")



if opened == "No":
    Tasks()




Save_Entry = Button(root, text="Save Tasks", command=save).grid(row=0, 
column=2)











root.mainloop()
```

This is how far I could get but all it can do is save it into a file.It can't load it into Labels.

Comment: You just need to be able to get the first line of the file into a string.  Then you can research how to get a string into a widget.  Please ask one problem at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first line of a file, you could use readline().

```
opened = open("Opened.txt", 'r')
first_line= str(opened.readline())
opened.close()
```

I'll note that you should close your file after opening it and you don't want to rename your file object to a string.

To get your string into a label you could do the following:

```
w = Label(master, text=first_line)
```

If you want to be cool, wrap the first_line into Stringvar() in order to make the text change with the string value.